# Implementing a stack in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need a way of doing the following in Prolog.

I want to have a list of variables defined. For example [x,z,k,s,r,v,w]

And then I want one of my functions to be able to pop the first element from the list, use it in some way, then when It needs another element I want it to pop the next element from that list. And perhaps when the function is finished I want it to reset the list to it's original state.

I can't think of a way of doing this by simple passing the list as an argument. This would be really simple with OO programming. As I could just have a global variable.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do and why simply getting the head of the list (L=[H|T]) wont work? sounds like you are thinking too imperatively

Comment: You could use _global variables_ (in SWI-Prolog, nb_setval/2, nb_getval/2), and use the _list accessor_ patterns to simulate a 'traditional' stack, but this approach often leads to hard to understand (and maintain) code, because violates the essence of Prolog programming, where we don't have _functions_, but _relations_ among the arguments of _procedures_. Then should specify better your requirements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but I think a stack is pretty simple to implement.

`pop([X|List],X,List).` will unify the head of the list with X, so you can you can use it as you wish. And `push(X,List,[X|List])` will unify the third argument a new List with X pushed at its head.

Or maybe I totally did't get you question...

Comment: `pop` needs a further argument for the new, popped stack.

Comment: your right of course. I will edit. So now the only different is the conceptual order of the arguments.

Comment: State arguments - here the lists - are usually written consecutively in the order Old, New.

Comment: I thought this is the way I wrote them, no? pop(The_old_stack,New_X,New_stack) and push(Old_x,Old_stack,New_stack)

Comment: For pop/3, you exchanged the first two arguments.  This makes it more difficult to see that argument 1 and 3 belong together.

Comment: I don't agree. they don't belong together. argument 1 is old, and 2 and 3 are new (you're poping from the old stack (1) and the result is the top element (2) and the new stack (3))

Comment: I explained you a frequent convention. No more.

Comment: I also find it more intuitive if state pairs of the form "State0, State1" appear as directly successive arguments, so I would also write pop(Element, Stack0, Stack), or pop(E, [E|Es], Es) if you settle on lists as a natural choice to represent a stack. As already noted in "false"'s reply, an alternative is to use DCG notation with right hand context, so you can implicitly thread the states through.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that the stack is implemented in a pure side effect free manner. Since no implicit state is used, everything has to be explicit. Usually, Prolog programmers use lists directly, or they use grammars (DCGs) for that purpose.

```
empty([]).

pop(E, [E|Es],Es).

push(E, Es, [E|Es]).

?- empty(S0), push(1,S0,S1),push(2,S1,S2),pop(T,S2,S3).
   S0 = [], S1 = [1], S2 = [2,1], T = 2, S3 = [1].
```